# Bash script gets killed by system

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a bash script which starts after a special device is plugged in. In this script a python script is executed:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "before python" >> /home/pi/log
/usr/bin/python3.2 pythonscript.py
echo "after python" >> /home/pi/log
```

The python scripts needs a lot of CPU, but only small amount of RAM. I see in htop, that both the shell script and python script are running. After some time, the shell script vanishes! The python script works fine to the end. But as the shell script is not there anymore, the second echo is never executed. Who is killing my script and why? (It works if the python script does not take too long)

Comment: does your python script also happen to write to /home/pi/log ?

Comment: Does the 'dmesg' command give you any information about what the system was doing, if you type it just after your bash script is killed?

Comment: what is starting your shellscript?

Comment: does the python fork?

Comment: The shell script is started by udev (RUN+=..."), The python script does not write to /home/pi/log, dmesg does not show any relevant information. I am using a Raspberry Pi, and the python script uses 100% CPU. Is this a problem?

Comment: Hm, if there was a limit on cpu usage (`ulimit -a`) I'd expect the python script to get killed. I wonder what signal the bash script is receiving? You could add handlers for SIGTERM, SIGKILL, SIGCHLD, as they'll be most likely.

Comment: Allready found a system on which the sysadmin had added a kind of watchdog that killed all processes except a limited command list if they lasted more than n minutes ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got an solution for this from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in/28711#28711

It seems udev is killing my bash script, but not the python script. Therefore I have to detach the process somehow. I solved it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "/home/pi/mipod/src/script_taking_long.sh $1" | at now
```

The reason for the behaviour seems to be a timeout from udev? If anyone can clarify this, it would help.